# Javascript sends data to laravel controller

Tags: laravel, controller

I am trying to send two javascript variable to laravel controller. I tried like this :

Javascript

```
        var univ_id = 1;
        var user_id = 2;


        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/yes_subscription/",
        data: {
            'univ_id' : univ_id,
            'user_id' : user_id,
        },
        dataType: 'html',

        });
```

in routes I have set up like this :

```
Route::get('/yes_subscription', 'CommunityController@yes_subscription')->middleware('authcustom');
```

In controller I have set this :

```
    public function yes_subscription(Request $request)
{

    $univ_id = $request->input('univ_id');
    print ($univ_id);

}
```

But nothing is printed. I know I am doing something wrong because I am following Django method for sending variable . How can I apply this in laravel here ?What steps should I take ?  Using Laravel 5.4.36

Comment: have you specifiedm ajax headers?

Comment: set it.But no luck here also.

Comment: Change `type = "GET",` to `method = "GET",`. Check full [example here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Changed it . No luck yet .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you have not setup AJAX headers in your JavaScript, an example is the following:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var univ_id = 1;
        var user_id = 2;

        var postData = {
                'univ_id' : univ_id,
                'user_id' : user_id
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/yes_subscription/',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('data', data);
            }
        });
```

This assumes you are using JQuery and also if you are not posting simple data, it might be better to use a POST request.

Comment: No luck . All changed to POST and set the headers. But can not pass the variable .